# Function return values in R

Tags: r, function

```
trainer <- function(training, testing){    
  trControl <- trainControl(method="cv", number=5)
  modelFit <- train(training$classe ~ ., method="rf", preProcess="pca", 
                    trControl=trControl, data=training)
  confMatrix <- confusionMatrix(testing$classe, predict(modelFit,testing))

  output <- list(modelFit, confMatrix)
  return(output)
}
```

The returned value is supposed to be a model, `modelFit`, which isn't a list, But when I check `class(output[1])`, it reports as a list. Seems somehow the model file is converted to a list. How to retain the original data type without converting it a list, because I need to access the model file in the return.

Comment: Try `class(output[[1]])` (see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1169456/489704))

Comment: use  double brackets:  `class(output[[1]])`

Comment: Also note that you don't need the assignment and `return` statements. Like in Lisp, the last sub-expression in a complex expression is the value of the complex expression, so if your last line is `list(modelFit, confMatrix)` , then that list will indeed be the return value. In fact, `return` isn't viewed as good style.

Comment: The assignment and `return` have a slight overhead, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated above, when `output` is a list and you use `[ ]` to extract elements, you will always get a list back (with the element or elements for the index you specified). However, when you use `[[ ]]` you will extract the element at a particular position and that element may have a different class.

You could do `sapply(output, class)` to see the classes of all the items in a given list.

So your function seems to be working fine, just make sure you use `output<-trainer(...); output[[1]]` to extract your model.